# Problemas con css, nose si es problema de padding o margin

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

Estoy teniendo este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la verdad nose a que se debe porque no toque ni el **margin** ni el **padding**. Mi etiqueta **nav** esta dentro del **header**, que en el header es la única etiqueta que hay. Mi código es el siguiente para hacer el nav

```
#header{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 5px gainsboro;
background: black;
}

#menu{
padding-bottom: 13px;
margin: auto;
}

#menu ul a{
font: 17px Century Gothic;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 12px 25% 17px 25%;
text-align: center;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
background-color: grey;
color: white;
}
```

Y después tengo el siguiente caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi **banner** se pone encima de mí **nav**. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Coloca tu HTML por favor para poder reproducir el problema completo y darte una solución

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a quitar todo el margin y padding por defecto en el HTML con:

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

Y por lo que veo también la imagen se superpone por delante por que tienes que quitar el position:fixed de la etiqueta header.